# Program that finds Highest, Lowest, and Average of 5 number from an Array

Tags: c++, arrays

My homework is to write a program that finds the highest, lowest, and average of 5 numbers in an Array that the user inputs. Here is my problem, the user does not have to enter all 5 numbers. But has to enter at least 2 numbers minimum.

I have the whole program done already I am having a problem with the beginning, below is my code where I am having a problem:

```
// Ask for name and explain program
cout << "Please enter your name: ";
cin >> name;
cout << endl;
cout << "Hi " << name << ", please enter up to 5 whole numbers." << endl;
cout << "I will find the HIGHEST, LOWEST, and AVERAGE number." << endl;

// Loop through users input
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter number " << (i + 1) << " : ";
    cin >> number[i];

    // Validate that the user has entered atleast 2 numbers
    if (i >= 1 && i < 4)
    {
        cout << "Do you wish to enter another number (Y/N)? : ";
        cin >> continue_game;

        // Validate that the user only enters Y/N
        while (continue_game != 'Y' && continue_game != 'y' && continue_game != 'N' && continue_game != 'n')
        {
            cout << "Please type in (Y/N): ";
            cin >> continue_game;
        }

        // What happens if user chooses NO
        if (continue_game == 'N' || continue_game == 'n') 
        {
            i = 5;
        }

        // What happens if user chooses YES
        else if (continue_game == 'Y' || continue_game == 'y')
        {
            i = i;
        }
    }
}
```

PROBLEM: If the user presses no after the 2nd number the remaining elements get a number asigned to them like : -8251616. Is there any way to make sure that the elements get assigned a zero or stay blank please help its due tomorrow and I can not figure it out.

SIZE = 5

Comment: Store the size when they exit (i.e. `final_size = i`) and use that when looping and calculating your results instead of `SIZE` so you won't check those undefined spots. I recommend this because even if they're 0, they'll still affect your calculated average - the best thing to do is just ignore them.

Comment: When you define an array locally inside a function and don't initialize it, the contents is *indeterminate* and reading it will lead to *undefined behavior*. You need to explicitly initialize all entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want zeros you need to fill array with zeros:

```
int number[5] = {};
```

or

```
int number[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    number[i] = 0;
}
```

However this will give wrong output if the user enter less than 5 numbers. What you should do is to count how many numbers user entered and then use values from `0` to `count - 1`.

Advice, use `break;` instead of `i = 5;`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't set `i = 5` when the user says no. Just end the loop with a `break;` statement.

Also, the `i = i;` statement in the yes case is useless.

When you're getting the highest, lowest, and average values, make sure you only look at the values from `0` to `i-1`, so you don't access the uninitialized elemends of the array.